# JS: drag and drop returning error

Tags: jquery, html, function, events, drag-and-drop

I have the following code but can not get it to work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- add jquery -->

<div class="dropzone" style="width: 180px; height: 180px; padding: 10px; margin: 0px; border: 1px solid black;"></div><br>
<div class="dropzone" style="width: 180px; height: 180px; padding: 10px; margin: 0px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <img class="dragable" src="https://image.spreadshirtmedia.net/image-server/v1/compositions/22839312/views/1,width=300,height=300,version=1478003241/smiley-smile-men-s-t-shirt.jpg" width="180">
</div>
<script>
    $(".dropzone").on("dragover", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    });

    $(".dropzone").on("drop", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    });

    $(".dragable").on("dragstart", function(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yv6uuzxn/

It is a simple drag and drop function. It works find when I have the `ondragstart`, `ondrop`, and `ondragover` inside the `div` and `img` tag but when I moved it to the script I start getting errors. 
`drag and drop.php:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined` and `drag and drop.php:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setData' of undefined`. It is probably something simple that I'm over looking, but I cant find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the propertie `draggable="true"` and an ID `id="myImg"` to your smiley image.
Then, if you set and get the `dataTransfer` event property into the `originalEvent`, it works fine.
;)

```js
$(".dropzone").on("dragover", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
});

$(".dropzone").on("drop", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
});

$(".dragable").on("dragstart", function(ev) {
  ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropzone" style="width: 180px; height: 180px; padding: 10px; margin: 0px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
<br>
<div class="dropzone" style="width: 180px; height: 180px; padding: 10px; margin: 0px; border: 1px solid black;">
  <img class="dragable" draggable="true" id="myImg" src="https://image.spreadshirtmedia.net/image-server/v1/compositions/22839312/views/1,width=300,height=300,version=1478003241/smiley-smile-men-s-t-shirt.jpg" width="180">
</div>
```

Comment: This REALLY helped me out.